# How do you actually train a model to make predictions on new inputed data?

Tags: data-mining, cross-validation

I created a system for my thesis, this system can predict whether something will succeed or fail. I use k-fold cross validation to see the performance, then the model that will be used to predict new data from the user will be trained using the entire dataset. But my lecturer said that the model that will be used to predict new inputed data uses a model from k-fold cross validation

So how do you actually train a model to make predictions on new inputed data?

I looked for several sources and asked on chatGPT that what I had done was correct, but because of the input from my lecturer, I wasn't sure.